# "Sure as a winter's day in springtime"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "Sure as a winter's day in springtime". Here is an example of usage: "Sure as a winter's day in springtime, Little Charlotte, I'm going to win that competition for you."

Comment: I won't 'answer', as the dearth of Google hits (in spite of the film) for the simile indicates it is unidiomatic, but it clearly means 'as sure as eggs is eggs'.

Comment: ***As sure as I'm standing here***, @Edwin has nailed it. But "sure as shit" you'd be wrong if you assumed I'm *actually* standing anywhere - I'm just sitting in a chair using an idiom.

Comment: (Oh - I forgot ***Sure as God made them little green apples***.)

Comment: Probably a variant of “as sure as spring follows winter”, but “a winter’s day in springtime”  is odd indeed.

Comment: @user 66974 Doubtless domain-specific (geographical domain). Reminds one of the well-known sayings in various parts of the UK (and doubtless elsewhere) along the lines of  'If you don't like the weather, wait for half an hour' and 'If you're getting wet, it's raining. If you're not, it's about to rain.'

Answer (score 2):

It is tempting to take the quotation literally. I give you the example of eastern Scotland:

> Average April daily high and low temperatures are 10ºC and 2ºC
>
> Average January daily high and low temperatures are 5ºC and -1ºC
>
> [Current Results](https://www.currentresults.com/Weather/United-Kingdom/Scotland/temperature-rainfall-average-january.php)

This means that in April there is a good chance that the average daily low temperature will be as low or lower than some of the days in January. Hence, we may be reasonably sure that spring will contain days typical of cold winter days, despite the naïve idea that spring is warmer than winter.

Similarly, despite the apparent unlikeliness of the speaker winning the competition, it is reasonably certain that they will.

Comment: Yes!  *Unlike* 'eggs is eggs', 'green apples' and the others listed in comments - this version stresses the element of surprise. Winter-type days often occur Spring, but they are unpredictable.

Comment: @Dan Thanks. Living in eastern Scotland, and at this time of year, I am uncomfortably aware of the truth of this saying.